# When are questions about crystals on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

We have a few questions about crystal formation and properties, for example:

- [Why does the colour of amethyst fade if exposed to too much light?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/345/why-does-the-colour-of-amethyst-fade-if-exposed-to-too-much-light)
- [Why do crystals, like quartz and diamonds, form in different colors?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/322/why-do-crystals-like-quartz-and-diamonds-form-in-different-colors)
- [How and where do double-terminated crystals form?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/324/how-and-where-do-double-terminated-crystals-form)

My feeling is that all three of these questions would be better suited to Chemistry.SE. However, I can see that there may be other cases where crystal-related questions might be more geochemical. Anyone have any ideas for guidelines on how to decide when a question like this is more suited to Chemistry.SE or here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My opinion:

- 1) Could be at either site.
- 2) Should be here. Natural crystallization should be here. Artificial crystallization at chemistry.
- 3) Should be here. Beause it is natural crystallization.

A rough guidline:

- Natural compounds and minerals should be on this page. Also question how to measure them, classify them, ...
- Artificial compounds at chemistry.
- Cut-off point for natural compounds after they leave the primary resource status. Example: High-purity-Quartz-sand questions go here, but questions about the usage of it in microchips should go to chemistry.

Comment: That's a good point, I didn't think about the environmental impacts of crystal formation.

Comment: Yes to me mineralogy is definitely on topic, and the natural / artificial line seems a reasonable one.

Comment: I totally agree with this answer. +1

Comment: Mineralogy is a branch of Earth Science. (Definition: A subject of geology specializing in the scientific study of chemistry, crystal structure, and physical properties of minerals.) Which I would think includes crystals...